# Linking a series of GCP disks to corresponding instances dynamically in terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I need to dynamically create a variable number of riak instances, each with an attached disk across multiple zones in GCP using terraform.

Each attached disk must live in the same zone as its instance.

Upon `terraform plan` everything looked good, but when I ran `apply` terraform responded with an error saying that zone was undefined.

Okay, I thought, let's set the zone to be the same as the linked instance.  No dice.  Cycle error, so I move everything such that the information flows from the disk to the instance, but the cycle error persists.  Here's the error:

```
│ Error: Cycle: module.riak_instances.google_compute_instance.riak_instance, module.riak_instances.google_compute_disk.data-disk
```

And the code in it's current incarnation:

```
data "google_compute_zones" "zones" {
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "riak_instance" {
  count = var.instance_count
  name = "riak-${count.index + 1}"
  machine_type = var.machine_type
  zone = google_compute_disk.data-disk[count.index].zone

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = var.disk_image
      size = var.instance_disk_size
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = "default"
  }

  attached_disk {
    source = google_compute_disk.data-disk[count.index].self_link
  }

  labels = {
    environment = var.environment
    owner = var.owner
  }
}

resource "google_compute_disk" "data-disk" {
  count = var.instance_count
  name = "riak-disk-${count.index + 1}"
  type = "pd-balanced"
  size = var.data_disk_size
  zone = data.google_compute_zones.zones.names[count.index]

  labels = {
    environment = var.environment
    owner = var.owner
  }
}
```

Comment: I think You have a "depends_on" problem. The data-disk must be created before the instance can reference it. https://www.terraform.io/language/configuration-0-11/resources#depends_on

Comment: You need to do two things here
1. Add depends_on key
2. Also create a provider and set a zone in the provider so that all the resources will spin up in the same zone